# How to use keystroke Events for <apex:InputField>?

Tags: visualforce, community

I want to use keystroke events to check the limit of a rich text box .
I am using Input field for that. As we are not able to directly use events  for inputfield for rich text box . Is there a way so that i can use events on inputfield which is holding rich text ??

Answer (score 2):

```
<script>
 function testMe(e , f){
     console.log(e);
     console.log(f);
     if(f != '0'){
         runMeApex(f);
     }
 }
</script>

<apex:actionFunction name="runMeApex" action="{!testAction}" rerender="Details">

<apex:inputText value="{!w.name}" onkeyup="testMe(event);" />
```

you can use action function to check the limit of a rich text box using key up event. here i have only given a deme code if you want to run you code then either you can crate you own controller or you can use java script.

Comment: For <apex:inputText> events can be placed directly I am asking can we fire events on <apex:inputField> ??

Comment: yes, events can be directly placed in <apex:inputfield>

Comment: i have tried using a simple function to display an alert message ...
it was working fine for everything but not for rich text area...

Answer (score 1):

You can use plain vannila Javascript to do this.

The Visualforce portion will look like

```
<apex:outputPanel id="myTASize12">{!LEN(i_objRMADeviceDetail.Problem_Description__c)} / 250</apex:outputPanel>                                                                                            
<apex:inputField id="ProbDescriptFld" value="{!i_objRMADeviceDetail.Problem_Description__c}" label="Problem Description:" html-maxlength="250"onchange="ShowCharCount(this, 250, '{!$Component.myTASize12}');" onmousedown="ShowCharCount(this, 250, '{!$Component.myTASize12}');" onkeyup="ShowCharCount(this, 250, '{!$Component.myTASize12}');" onkeydown="ShowCharCount(this, 250, '{!$Component.myTASize12}');" onclick="ShowCharCount(this, 250, '{!$Component.myTASize12}');"/>
```

The Javascript method look like

```
function ShowCharCount(myTA,maxSize,SizeLabel) {                  
    if(myTA.value.length > maxSize)
        myTA.value = myTA.value.substring(0,maxSize);
    document.getElementById(SizeLabel).innerHTML = myTA.value.length + ' / 250';
}
```

The user won't be able to enter more than 250 characters in the input field. We are showing the counter on top of it aswell.

Hope it helps.